# Unable to access Registration Screen dropdown Civievnts

Tags: civievent

[image]This is probably not a Civi issue, but any feedback would be appreciated. I have set up an event. Under Registration Screen, I have the option to Include Profile Top of Page and Include Profile Bottom of the Page. When I select an option in either or both fields and save, I am not able to access either field again. They are both greyed out. After much work with a colleague yesterday, we established this occurs only in Firefox. I have logged into Microsoft Edge and I am able to access the dropdown. I like using Firefox and I don't want to have to change between browsers when using Civi. Is there a way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: The issue appears to happen in Chrome as well, but not MS Edge.

Comment: Can you pls look at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/manage/registration?reset=1&action=update&id=3#/volunteer/manage/0 and tell me if the same behaviour exists. not sure if this is only a problem for a new event, if so pls replicate on demo. thx.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will follow up and get back to you.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion. I set up a new event in the demo site. The same behaviour is not replicated. It is still happening in our Civi site in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Opera and Edge. A colleague says that it does not happen for her in Firefox.I have also tried accessing the site from a different laptop - the same thing happens. It has me stumped.

Comment: are you on latest civi? if not perhaps worth upgrading

Comment: @petednz-fuzion. We have Civi 5.26.2 installed. I will work on getting the latest version installed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion. I think I worked the issue out. I have Dashlane, a password manager extension, installed on Chrome and Firefox. I have had the issue where it conflicts with Javascript on sites before. I restarted Firefox in safe mode, with extensions disabled and I can access the dropdowns. I have raised the issues with Dashlane before, but they don't seem to care. Thanks for your help with this. It also answers the question why a colleague was able to access Civi on Firefox and Chrome without problems. It's funny that it doesn't occur with the Civi version on my own website. I will upgrade.

Comment: Ah ha. Yep I use Privacy Badger which also causes some forms to fail (not civi ones) and I have to remember to turn it off before complaining to the site owners that their sites are broken.

Comment: Perhaps you could add as your own Answer to help close this off

Answer (score 1):

Some of the forms on Civicrm won't allow me to access dropdown menus. The menus are greyed out. I thought this was a browser issue as it happens only on Firefox and Chrome, but not on MS Edge. It is caused by the Dashlane password extension. I started Firefox in safe mode, with extensions disabled. The issue goes away. I have removed Dashlane from Firefox and Chrome. Civi is working well.